# Looking for a way to load 1 of 5 sections of a partial

Tags: dust.js

I'm trying to find a way to load 1 section of a partial that would have 5 sections in all.
The idea behind it is to load either the US, UK, DE, FR or DU section of a partial depending the countryCode. CountryCode gets loading into {sys.pageInfo.countryCode}

I've been able to find an @if condition but this only works if I want to load 1 of 2 sections

```
{@if cond="'{countryCode}' == 'US'"}
<p>is country code US</p>
{:else}
<p>is NOT country code US</p>
{/if}
```

or

```
{@eq key=countryCode value="US"}
<p>is country code US</p>
{:else}
<p>is NOT country code US</p>
{/eq}
```

@eq was working but doesn't seem to be working for me atm.

Again the above works well to load 1 or 2 sections but I need a way to load 1 of 5 sections. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: the eq is working fine, I tested you code and it works. did you include the dust-helpers.js file??? because the eq is a dust helper. More info here: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial

Comment: Thanks - any ideas on how to get an {@if... to load 1 of 5 different sections of a page/partial?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{@select}`.

```
{@select key="{countryCode}"}
  {@eq value="US"}Hi{/eq}
  {@eq value="UK"}Hello{/eq}
  {@eq value="FR"}Bonjour{/eq}
  {@default}Hello{/default}
{/select}
```